# Placing div next to each other

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am having div tables like in the example.

There is `ng-repeat` angularjs which generates smaller divs inside one big wrapper div. And all that is centered. What I want is to place one smaller div on the right side of this `wrapper_main` div, with `wrapper_main` div still being in the center. I tried adding `display:inline-block` and nothing happened. `float:left` moved everything to the left which isn't what I want.

```css
/* Styles go here */

div.pomocni_profil {
 margin: auto;
 width: 50%;
 border: solid chocolate medium;
 border-radius: 5%;
 display: inline-block;
}

div.pomocni_profil p{
 color: black;
 font-size: 14;
}

div.pratimPratioci {
 width: 200px;
 height: 500px;
 border: solid chocolate medium;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

div.wrapper_profil_glavni {
 height: 100%;
 width: 50%;
 margin: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 border: solid chocolate medium;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<center>
<div class="wrapper_profil_glavni" >
<div class="aktivnosti_glavni" ng-repeat="aktivnost in aktivnosti">
  <div class="pomocni_profil">
  <center>
   <p class="naslov">{{aktivnost.aktivnost.naslov}} </p>
   <p><img alt="{{aktivnost.korisnik.username}}" ng-src="/trcanje/services/rest/profilna/{{aktivnost.korisnik.username}}?imeSlike={{aktivnost.korisnik.slika}}" height="50px"> </img> </p><!-- aktivnost.slika je slika korisnika koji je obavio aktivnost -->
   <p><a href="#" ng-click = "otvoriProfil(aktivnost.korisnik.username)" >{{aktivnost.korisnik.username}} </a></p>
   <br />
   <!-- TODO: da pise ime i prezime -->
   <p class="datum">{{aktivnost.aktivnost.datumFormatiran}} </p>
   <p>
   {{aktivnost.aktivnost.tempo}}/km  {{aktivnost.aktivnost.distanca}} km</p>
   <p>Vreme: {{aktivnost.aktivnost.trajanje}}</p>
   <br />
   <table><tr><th><input type="image" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/slike/lajk.png" height="25px" ng-click="lajkuj(ulogovaniKorisnik.username, aktivnost.aktivnost.id);"/></th><th>{{aktivnost.brojLajkova}}</th></tr></table>
  </center>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
 </div>
  <div ng-if="(aktivnosti.length < ukupanBrojAktivnosti) && aktivnosti.length > 0"><center><a href="#!" ng-click="ucitajJos('${userDetails.username }')">Ucitaj jos</a></center></div>
 <br/>
</div>
</center>
  </body>

<div class = "pratimPratioci">

</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: Can you add styles for both `class`?

Comment: Also set height, width along with float:left, better provide js-fiddle or plunker

Comment: @Satindersingh I can't create plunker because I have angularjs which want work..

Comment: @wdc direct paste your resulted HTML into it, this is only HTML CSS problem, nothing to do with angular js

Comment: text-align:right to the parent div.

Comment: @Satindersingh Ok, it does show the problem.

Comment: @Roy that just made inner div align to the right, nothing to do with this separate div I want to place on the right of wrapper.

Comment: Please mention the class name of the div which has to be placed right.

Comment: @SaravananI The one on the bottom named `pratimPratioci`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can Make `pratimPratioci` div `position absolute` and move it to top right. Or
2. Place the `pratimPratioci` div before `center` div in `html` and style it to `float:left`

```css
/* Styles go here */

div.pomocni_profil {
 margin: auto;
 width: 50%;
 border: solid chocolate medium;
 border-radius: 5%;
 display: inline-block;
}

div.pomocni_profil p{
 color: black;
 font-size: 14;
}

div.pratimPratioci {
 width: 200px;
 height: 500px;
 border: solid chocolate medium;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
      position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

div.wrapper_profil_glavni {
 height: 100%;
 width: 50%;
 margin: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 border: solid chocolate medium;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<center>
<div class="wrapper_profil_glavni" >
<div class="aktivnosti_glavni" ng-repeat="aktivnost in aktivnosti">
  <div class="pomocni_profil">
  <center>
   <p class="naslov">{{aktivnost.aktivnost.naslov}} </p>
   <p><img alt="{{aktivnost.korisnik.username}}" ng-src="/trcanje/services/rest/profilna/{{aktivnost.korisnik.username}}?imeSlike={{aktivnost.korisnik.slika}}" height="50px"> </img> </p><!-- aktivnost.slika je slika korisnika koji je obavio aktivnost -->
   <p><a href="#" ng-click = "otvoriProfil(aktivnost.korisnik.username)" >{{aktivnost.korisnik.username}} </a></p>
   <br />
   <!-- TODO: da pise ime i prezime -->
   <p class="datum">{{aktivnost.aktivnost.datumFormatiran}} </p>
   <p>
   {{aktivnost.aktivnost.tempo}}/km  {{aktivnost.aktivnost.distanca}} km</p>
   <p>Vreme: {{aktivnost.aktivnost.trajanje}}</p>
   <br />
   <table><tr><th><input type="image" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/slike/lajk.png" height="25px" ng-click="lajkuj(ulogovaniKorisnik.username, aktivnost.aktivnost.id);"/></th><th>{{aktivnost.brojLajkova}}</th></tr></table>
  </center>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
 </div>
  <div ng-if="(aktivnosti.length < ukupanBrojAktivnosti) && aktivnosti.length > 0"><center><a href="#!" ng-click="ucitajJos('${userDetails.username }')">Ucitaj jos</a></center></div>
 <br/>
</div>
</center>
  </body>

<div class = "pratimPratioci">

</div>

</html>
```